# Parse text file tags as xml - Java

Tags: java, xml, file, parsing

I have a logs text file consists of several tags like the following:

```
<log level="info" id="12144" ....> <msg> test msg </msg> </log>
```

I want to parse this file, therefore I thought that since it looks like XML I can add the xml (`<?xml version="1.0"?`>) and a root (`<file>`) tags to the file and then parse it with DOM Parser.

But currently, I am facing an issue to add text at the beginning of the file, since all available options are to overwrite, or to copy the original file to a temporary location and then add the intended text, which is not applicable for me as I am dealing with files bigger than 100 MB.

```
I use the below code to try to add the text at the beginning, and I tried several solutions or classes other than RandomAccessFile

RandomAccessFile RAF = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        RAF.getChannel().position(0);

        RAF.write(("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \r\n <file> \r\n").getBytes()); 

        RAF.close();
```

Do you have any suggestions to add the text at the beginning or to parse the text file as it is and extract elements?

THanks,

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you know the exact pattern of the entries and **if** that pattern doesn't change then it's relatively easy to extract the entries with regular expressions, e.g.:

```
"<log *level=\"([^\"]*)\" *id=\"([^\"])\" *> ..."
```

Comment: Nice suggestion @maraca, I will try it.

Comment: I'm very careful with the suggestion, because usually regex are not suited for xml/html and often referred to this famous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4785110

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get the content of the file as `String` or `Stream` or whatever and then add your stuff to the beginning? After that you still can parse the document `String/Stream` whatever

Comment: Files are very big, and to get the contents out to add the string, would not fit to the memory i think since I am working on a web service we might process several files at a moment. That's why I excluded this option from my solutions.